# ConcurrentHashMap dilemma in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

`CocncurrentHashMap` provides a method to atomically check and add an element if it is not present via `putIfAbsent` method as shown in the example below

```
xmlObject = new XMLObejct(xmlId);
mapOfXMLs.putIfAbsent(xmlId, xmlObject);
```

However my dilemma is that , I have to create that `xmlObject` in advance. Is there a way to postpone the object creation after the key present check.

I want all three things below to happen atomically

1. Check if the key present
2. Create object if key is not present.
3. Add the object to map.

I know I can achieve this using `synchronized` block , If I am using a synchronized block , why use a `CocurrentHashMap`?

Comment: you want to check object is present as key before it gets created ?

Comment: Why not use `Future<XMLObject>`s as values, then?

Comment: If your typical use case one where duplicate object creation is a concern?

Comment: @fge This works, but I've found that that the wrong Future implementation has a ```get()``` that's so slow you might as well use double-checked locking for writes to the ConcurrentMap.

Comment: Future<> looks like a good idea but how do I guarantee that only one object gets created do you have a sample @David Ehrmann yes duplicate object creation is a concern as XMLObject creation involves both NIO and DB?

Comment: @Puru-- this is in `Future`'s contract; once the computation is over, the result is retained (until the reference to the `Future` falls out of scope of course)

Comment: @fge could you provide a sample on how I can use future in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Guava Caches offer such a functionality ( http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained ) though it's somewhat hidden.

If you can already use Java 8, then you can use [computeIfAbsent](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). But I guess if you *could* use it, you would not have asked....

Answer (score 2):

The standard, almost perfect pattern is this:

```
Foo foo = map.get(key);
if(foo == null) {
    map.putIfAbsent(new Foo());
    foo = map.get(key);
}
```

It does sometimes result in an extra object, but extremely infrequently, so from a performance standpoint is certainly fine. It only wouldn't be fine if constructing your object inserted into a database or charged a user or some such.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this scenario a couple of times, and they allowed for the *value* to be created lazily. It may not apply to your use case, but if it does, this is basically what I did:

```
static abstract class Lazy<T> {

    private volatile T value;

    protected abstract T initialValue();

    public T get() {
        T tmp = value;
        if (tmp == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                tmp = value;
                if (tmp == null)
                    value = tmp = initialValue();
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}

static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Lazy<XmlObject>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

and then populating the map:

```
    final int id = 1;

    map.putIfAbsent(id, new Lazy<XmlObject>() {
        @Override
        protected XmlObject initialValue() {
            return new XmlObject(id);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(map.get(id).get());
```

You can of course create a specialized `LazyXmlObject` for convenience:

```
static class LazyXmlObject extends Lazy<XmlObject> {
    private final int id;

    public LazyXmlObject(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected XmlObject initialValue() {
        return new XmlObject(id);
    }
}
```

and the usage would be:

```
    final int id = 1;

    map.putIfAbsent(id, new LazyXmlObject(id));

    System.out.println(map.get(id).get());
```

Comment: forty-two this is exactly what I currently have and was trying to see if I can replace it with concurrent hashmap

Comment: No, it's no exactly what you have. In your case, you could create the XmlObject more times than necessary, in my case it would be created at most once.

Comment: No, what I presented in the code is to find out how to use `ConcurrentHashmap` efficiently without using double check locking idiom. I am currently using double check locking in my code.

Comment: Well, that wasn't obvious at all. Anyway, happy coding :)